# GOJS VUE Vue cli -> Vite migration

Tags: vue.js, vite, gojs

I have a large vue 2 project that I am migrating from vue cli to vite and I am down to one dependency that is not working.  I use gojs 2.1.51 in my project for many years now but when using the same code and data but using vite instead of vue cli I get

````
chunk-JHIOXJJP.js?v=d4bd4acf:2020 TypeError: Cannot set property layer of [object Object] which has only a getter
    at Aj (gojs.js?v=507ae5dd:12130:16)
    at Rl (gojs.js?v=507ae5dd:16930:13)
    at Pl (gojs.js?v=507ae5dd:16876:136)
    at Object.initGraph (bizStore.js:133:5)
    at VueComponent.mounted (valueNetwork.vue:165:1)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (chunk-JHIOXJJP.js?v=d4bd4acf:1991:57)
    at callHook$1 (chunk-JHIOXJJP.js?v=d4bd4acf:2584:7)
    at Object.insert (chunk-JHIOXJJP.js?v=d4bd4acf:6226:11)
    at invokeInsertHook (chunk-JHIOXJJP.js?v=d4bd4acf:4441:31)
    at VueComponent.patch2 [as __patch__] (chunk-JHIOXJJP.js?v=d4bd4acf:4608:5)```

Anytime I try to add a groupTemplateMap
sd.diagram.groupTemplateMap.add(...)

If I switch back to using the vue cli instead of vite it works just fine.  I known there is not a lot of information here to help debug, but I just wanted to know if anyone else has run into issues with gojs and vite or got it to work.
````

Comment: Yes, there's not enough debug info. There's nothing in Vite itself that could cause something like that. This is very specific to your case and needs to be debugged. Unless you're able to provide a way to reproduce, you'll have to do this yourself, by adding breakpoints to specified places and checking what's wrong with data, and why

Answer (score 0):

The issue, if anyone else runs into this, turned out to be a combination of a bad GOJS argument and the way Vite compiles GOJS.  Instead of getting a GOJS error, like we do with webpack, I got an exception deep in the minimized GOJS code. The GOJS team was great in helping debug this issue.

From the GOJS team:  use method chaining instead of our $/go.GraphObject.make, it should be able to give you more sensible errors.